# DynamicFactorMQ(): ValueError: Constant variable(s) found in observed variables, but constants cannot be included in this model

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I try to use `sm.tsa.DynamicFactorMQ()` for dynamic factor modeling: `sm.tsa.DynamicFactorMQ(endog=endog, k_endog_monthly=1, factors=1, factor_orders=1)` can return the results normally, but I added parameter `exog` of the exogenous variable to the model, `point_forecasts` part can no longer return the result normally.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True, linewidth=120)
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader

def get_predictions(model_fit, start, end):
    historical_predictions = model_fit.get_prediction(start=start, end=end)
    return historical_predictions.predicted_mean

start = '1979-01-01'
end = '2014-12-01'
indprod = DataReader('IPMAN', 'fred', start=start, end=end)
income = DataReader('W875RX1', 'fred', start=start, end=end)
sales = DataReader('CMRMTSPL', 'fred', start=start, end=end)
emp = DataReader('PAYEMS', 'fred', start=start, end=end)
dta = pd.concat((indprod, income, sales, emp), axis=1)
dta.columns = ['indprod', 'income', 'sales', 'emp']

dta['dln_indprod'] = (np.log(dta.indprod)).diff() * 100
dta['dln_income'] = (np.log(dta.income)).diff() * 100
dta['dln_sales'] = (np.log(dta.sales)).diff() * 100
dta['dln_emp'] = (np.log(dta.emp)).diff() * 100
dta['std_indprod'] = (dta['dln_indprod'] - dta['dln_indprod'].mean()) / dta['dln_indprod'].std()
dta['std_income'] = (dta['dln_income'] - dta['dln_income'].mean()) / dta['dln_income'].std()
dta['std_sales'] = (dta['dln_sales'] - dta['dln_sales'].mean()) / dta['dln_sales'].std()
dta['std_emp'] = (dta['dln_emp'] - dta['dln_emp'].mean()) / dta['dln_emp'].std()

# endog = dta.loc['1979-02-01':, 'std_indprod']
endog = dta.loc['1979-02-01':, 'std_indprod':'std_income']
exog = dta.loc['1979-02-01':, 'std_sales':'std_emp']

mod = sm.tsa.DynamicFactorMQ(endog=endog, exog=exog, k_endog_monthly=1, factors=1, factor_orders=1)
res = mod.fit()
res.summary()

predicted_in_sample = get_predictions(res, 0, len(endog) - 1)
print(predicted_in_sample)
point_forecasts = res.forecast(steps=3)
print(point_forecasts)
```

Out:

```
ValueError: Constant variable(s) found in observed variables, but constants cannot be included in this model. These variables are: ['y1', 'y2'].
```

But if I removed `exog=exog` from `mod`, the result will be generated normally:

```
          std_indprod    std_income
1979-02-01     0.170186  5.383089e-01
1979-03-01     0.054428 -4.533073e+02
1979-04-01     0.121380  1.067321e+03
1979-05-01    -0.771963 -5.919572e+02
1979-06-01     0.500232 -4.300608e+02
                 ...           ...
2014-08-01     0.228435  6.215508e+08
2014-09-01    -0.140339 -1.076402e+09
2014-10-01    -0.305715  4.555700e+08
2014-11-01     0.004999  6.144828e+08
2014-12-01     0.370981 -1.064393e+09
[431 rows x 2 columns]
            std_indprod    std_income
2015-01-01    -0.413758  4.506101e+08
2015-02-01    -0.132331  1.279351e+09
2015-03-01    -0.042324  8.528376e+08
```

Does someone know how to deal with this issue? Many thanks.

Reference:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor_mq.DynamicFactorMQ.html